# C++, Map<> structure but with Gaps

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am trying to use a class to make a dictionary < key, value > in C++.

I found online that Map was the class I was suppoused to use.

However, when I try to use Map it FILLS the gaps between the keys.

This is an issue because keys are numbers, but they are incredibly sparse.

So in one set I may have the keys [1 , 20, 30000, 70000000]. I want my map to just store those 4 values, not every values between 1 and 70000000.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int,int> a = {{1,-1},{20,200}}; // I want this to just store {1,20}
    for(int x = 0; x < a.size(); x++) cout << a[p(x)] << ","; //however, when I print it I get [0,1..,19,20]
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,200,
```

Is there some workaround to avoid C++ from "filling the gaps" or any other class in the STD that can be used for that purpose?

Comment: `map::operator[]` create entry for you.

Comment: Thank you Apple, but that's not what I am asking.

Comment: I am looking for a class that can work like a dictionary without feeling the gaps

Comment: You would have compile error with `const map<int,int> a` in `a[p(x)]` usage.

Comment: What apple is saying is when you do a[p(x)] to dump the contents, it creates an entry. So apple's solution is to print the contents without using the [] operator, which does not fill the gaps

Comment: Don't prejudge. When something goes wrong, it can be wrong choice of tool, or it can be you using the right tool incorrectly. You prejudge it to be former. It is actually the later.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `map::operator[]` insert element, so `size()` increase

Comment: What did you expect `a[p(x)]` to output for values you did not put in?

Comment: @Jarod Ohhh.. I get it now. So instead of simply accessing the value, it fills the gap. Which means I should use being() and find() instead. What a bizzarre behaviour. Thanks Jarod,

Comment: @AppleApple thanks dude, I didn't get what you were trying to say at first.

Comment: Not so bizarre. It makes a  frequency counter very, very  easy to write: `map<string, int> freq;` `for (string& token: tokenlist) {freq[token]++;}` done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map::operator[]` create entry for you (and increase it's `size()`). If you just want to iterate through `std::map`, use it's iterator.

---

`for(auto& entry : a) cout << entry.second << ",";`

Answer (score 0):

As apple has commented, the operator[] creates the entry. See:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/

```
mapped_type& operator[] (const key_type& k);
```

If k does not match the key of any element in the container, the function inserts a new element with that key and returns a reference to its mapped value.

If you want to check existence of the key, use `map::find()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways to print out the map: you can use a for-each loop or an iterator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int, int> myMap;

    // filling map with random elements
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 rng(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(0,1000);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // uses the [] operator to create an element
        myMap[uni(rng)] = uni(rng);
    }

    // first method to print out map using for-each loop
    for(auto a : myMap) {
        // cannot change elements in map
        cout << a.first << " " << a.second << endl;
    }

    // second method to print out map using iterator
    for(map<int, int>::iterator it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); it++) {
        // can change elements in map
        cout << it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!
By the way, thinking of using map is actually very intelligent when creating a dictionary, because map elements are automatically sorted! I assume you are mapping `strings` to `ints`, right?